# hyper-v white black window

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-10, arch-linux, hyper-v

My host system is Windows Pro x64

When I open a hyper-v window, short seeing the hyper-v text. It is switching to that view:

[image]

As guest I tried arch, ubuntu and ubuntu-server. I also tried Gen1 and Gen2 both don't working. A buggy work around just with arch is to press enter on not visible bootmenu. After the save and start, but this don't working on ubuntu.

Any idea would help.

Answer (score 3):

It's a known problem between GRUB and Hyper-V during the installation. You can solve the problem with few steps.

**Requirement**

- SSH Server on VM

You need to check SSH Server at the installation to access to your VM without Hyper-V viewer.

**Solve black screen issue**

> Before any modification, be sure that you saved the files with : `cp <file> <file>.old`

Connect to your VM through SSH (e.g. using PuTTY or WinSCP) and edit the grub file:

`sudo vim /etc/default/grub`

Delete the "quiet splash" attribute in lines:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Uncomment the line:

```
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

Save the file before exit.

You also need to update grub to apply the new configuration:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot your VM with the following command:

```
sudo reboot
```

Try to access it through Hyper-V viewer.

Comment: I'll try it later and give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Most simple solution: open Cmd prompt as administrator and enter: "bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto"

Now the VM will work (at least for me it worked). I found this solution here (it works on Hyper-V as well, even if in the video it is VirtualBox): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3_BJQLNbe_o&ab_channel=VampyreDrakul

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).